# How do I create an SQL query that returns constant data?

Tags: sql

How do I create an SQL query that returns constant data?

Something like

select (("col1val1", "col2val1"), ("col1val2", "col2val2"))

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 'col1val1','col2val1'
UNION
SELECT 'col1val2','col2val2'
UNION
SELECT ...etc...
```

Write a macro to do this for you, do it in Excel (my favorite), or adjust your constraints.

Comment: Side note: you need to include 'FROM dual' if you do this on an Oracle server.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'col1val1', 'col2val1'
union
select 'col1val2', 'col2val2'
```

Comment: Thanks but that's really verbose for multiple rows.

Comment: you want to return hard codded constant data using SQL statement, unless you create some type of store procedure to create your dynamic SQL it will be verbose, the question is what is the reason for this? I bet there is better way of doing it

Comment: The reason is to stub out what will be an actual query that cannot be run yet in order to test the application.

Comment: another solution would be to create test data in your actual data store, when ready to release just remove it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to do that but you could use something like:

```
Select 'col1val1', 'col2val1', 'col1val2', 'col2val2' from ...
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on SQL Server. What delimits one row from another in your example?

Comment: sorry may be I miss nderstand you question, I have changed the doble quots by simple quots and it will retirn one row with 4 columns. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple, regular table.
2. Insert all data that you want there.
3. **REMOVE** insert, delete and update rights from all relevant loggable accounts (only for that table, of course).

*Voilà!* Now you have a constant, read-only table!! You can use regular `SELECT`s over it, and you'll never be worried by any kind of data change.

Other than that, sorry, your only option will be using `SELECT 'BlahBlahBlah' UNION...`...

Comment: That's actually probably what he's trying to do with the select statement. Populating the table isn't always so easy unfortunately